# Change 'File not found.' message with Nginx + PHP-FPM

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Is it possible to change the message displayed when a user tries to navigate to a PHP script that does not exist on the server. In my Nginx + PHP-FPM configuration it displays `File not found.` I would like to replace it with a custom error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, error pages can be customized: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page

Comment: If I recall correctly, this does not apply to PHP-FPM while using `location`

Comment: i think you need this: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_intercept_errors then it should be ok

Comment: We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.